# Can I write an HTML script and pass information from the script to a cell on Qubole?

Tags: html, angular, apache-zeppelin, qubole

Is it possible to write an HTML script and have the user interact on the HTML script and pass the data back to the zeppelin cell and have it rerun the data passed back?
Thank you!

Update:

Have some progress on rerunning the cell on a html click.

Cell I want to re-run and pass data into:
%pyspark
print("Hello "+ z.z.angular("input"))

or z.angular("input") depends on your zeppelin version.

Scrip to rerun the cell: 
stop

The next problem I have is how to pass a variable from java scrip into the z.z.angular("input")

Here is a link about how to do it using a button and input box in html.
https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.0/displaysystem/front-end-angular.html

Update

(https: //codepen.io/qwertynl/pen/jqIrK)
 This should solve most people's problem if you are able to call outside URL. I am still looking for solution from any one if there is a way to get it done without getting an external URL.

Answer (score 0):

Dillon, I found this

https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.8.0/usage/display_system/basic.html

I think it's will be helpful for you.here is everything to interact with HTML from Zeppelin. but otherwise, if you want to interact to zeppelin with HTML I think you might need work with forms

Comment: Thank you George! Yeah I am looking for having the HTML interact back with the zeppelin cell. For example the user looking at a html plot and want to look at another set of data. Is there a way to input a request on html and have zeppline get data from Hive to send to html again?

Comment: hello Dillon. sorry for response time. forms is when you work from HTML to backend i.e for example GET and PUT. you can read this . if my answer is good for you pls check it for answered . thanks <3 

https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.6.1/manual/dynamicform.html

https://docs.qubole.com/en/latest/user-guide/notebooks-and-dashboards/notebooks/zep-notebooks/dynamic-form.html

Comment: Oh, OK I can also use z.angular from non %angular cell! Cool! thanks for that. I think I am almost there. I am able to run a cell with a click on html now. I am still having some small problem about passing the variable into the %python cell from javascript function. The example here: https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.0/displaysystem/front-end-angular.html. Showed how to do it through a input and a button click. I am trying to figure out how to pass it from none input.